# Android RemoteView Notification with 3 Buttons having unexpected behavior

Tags: android, android-notifications, remoteview

I'm creating a custom notification using RemoteView with three buttons and a Label.
When I click on a button it is executing the PendingIntent of another. It is very strange.

When I click on 4G button it is executing Close PendingIntent

When I click on 3G button it is executing 4G PendingIntent

When I click on 2G button it is executing 3G PendingIntent

Code below:

```
RemoteViews remoteWidget = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.layout_notification);

    remoteWidget.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btn4G, getSwitchBandPendingIntent(context, "4G", 0));
    remoteWidget.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btn3G, getSwitchBandPendingIntent(context, "3G", 1));
    remoteWidget.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btn2G, getSwitchBandPendingIntent(context, "2G", 2));

    Intent closeIntent = new Intent("com.degelo.action.CLOSE_NOTIFICATION");
    PendingIntent closePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 3, closeIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    remoteWidget.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnClose, closePendingIntent);
    //remoteWidget.setTextViewText(R.id.labelCurrentPreferredBand, "Teste");

    Notification.Builder mBuilder =
            new Notification.Builder(context)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("Network Switcher")
                    .setContent(remoteWidget)
                    .setOngoing(true)
                    .setOnlyAlertOnce(true);        

    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);        
    nm.notify(1000, mBuilder.build());
```

getSwitchBandPendingIntent code:

```
private static PendingIntent getSwitchBandPendingIntent(Context context, String band, int requestCode) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, NetworkSwitcherService.class);
    intent.putExtra("BAND", band);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, requestCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    return pendingIntent;
}
```

and finally the layout xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/notificationLinearLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView android:id="@+id/labelCurrentPreferredBand"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Teste"
          style="@style/NotificationTitle" />

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="2G"
            android:id="@+id/btn2G" />

    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="3G"
            android:id="@+id/btn3G" />

    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="4G"
            android:id="@+id/btn4G" />

    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Close"
            android:id="@+id/btnClose" />
</LinearLayout> 
</LinearLayout>
```

style of textview:

```
<style name="NotificationText" parent="android:TextAppearance.StatusBar.EventContent" />
```

Thank you for helping.